# is my company taking advantage of me? need advice!

Tags: benefits, australia

Have been at my job for 3.5 years, started as an intern doing 2 days a week doing minor tasks.(work in IT, support team). on a contract with NO job description or mention of penalty rates or leave of any kind

As time goes on, my tasks and duties increase dramatically which is great. At the 2 year mark my IT manager left. They NEVER replaced him and naturally I took on his role as well as mine....with no pay rise, up-title or benefits.

3.5 years down the track i now run the entire support team, supervise a level 1 person who is BEING PAID MORE THAN ME. I do regular overtime, weekend and public holiday work and never gotten penalty rates. I also have never received a cent in leave of any kind.

My contract has NO job description and I feel my company owes me thousands in either leave or penalty rates....as they cannot decide whether I am casual or full/part time....

The problem is that when everything is fine, I'm just the support guy, but when things go wrong.. I'm suddenly the IT manager who knows what to do and can save the day

Comment: "naturally i took on his role as well as mine....with no pay rise, up-title or benefits" - Why?

Comment: i was a student at the time, i would take anything to have more experience..a flexible IT role so you can study is rarer than a unicorn

Comment: Where do you live? Do you have any kind of certification? Do you need such a thing in your country to get another (better) job? You said you studied, are you finished, did you get a degree?

Comment: 1. Sydney
2.  cert 4 in web dev
3. just finished uni, get my degree in September

Comment: This is common if this is your intern or your first job. 
People don't think that you have the freedom to leave the company within a  notice period. This is a democratic country, use your democracy. If you are good you can find any other opportunity easily. Don't try to complain or argue them, ask one time explaining them that your responsibilities are doubled as your living expenses so do a gental request about a salary increment.

Comment: This sounds a little ranty. And from your description and comment, you apparently accepted the situation (increased responsibility) in order to gain experience. Your degree will be done soon, so at that point you will be in a good position to move on to something better if desired.

Comment: Its my second IT job... i have over 5 years industry experience

Comment: A) We don't do personal advice, we answer practical questions. B) The language you use is inappropriate for this site. C) If you feel you're not being paid what you're worth you need to make your case for a raise, one won't appear like manna from heaven. D) When you take on a new role you should negotiate a raise. E) Questions should specify the location (I'm assuming Australia from your mention of penalty rates). F) "Please help me" is not a question.

Comment: It's a company goal to profit from anything it can : customers, employees, suppliers... business is not charity, you have to mind that. Fairness of the pay is something you have to evaluate yourself and you are the only responsible for it.

Comment: New hires being paid more than experienced workers ... is something that happens as job markets change. Don't be offended by it; do work with your manager  to understand what they need (and don't need) to see from you to justify your own next raise.

Answer (score 6):

> on a contract with NO job description or mention of penalty rates or
>   leave of any kind

You should probably try to get that amended. Sadly, your only bargaining power in this situation is threatening to leave if they don't, which can be a career limiting move.

> As time goes on, my tasks and duties increase dramatically which is
>   great. At the 2 year mark my IT manager left. They NEVER replaced him
>   and naturally i took on his role as well as mine....with no pay rise,
>   up-title or benefits.

You should have never done that. Always demand a clear definition of all your job duties and a fair compensation BEFORE you start doing it.

> 3.5 years down the track i now run the entire support team, supervise a level 1 person who is BEING PAID MORE THAN ME.

As brutal as this sounds, but thats in the best interest of the company. You've been not very thorough with trying to negotiate a fair salary, and it is in their interest to pay you as little as possible.

> I do regular overtime, weekend and public holiday work and never
>   gotten penalty rates. I also have never received a cent in leave of
>   any kind.

Again, thats unfortunate, but thats something you have to negotiate (If there is no laws setting minimums for this)

> My contract has NO job description and i feel my company owes me
>   thousands in either leave or penalty rates....as they cannot decide
>   whether i am casual or full/part time....

What you feel and what is legally required are most likely two different things. The only person who can help you find out the latter is a lawyer. I suggest you consult one.

> Can someone please help me? unions dont want to tell me anything
>   unless i pay them, but what im being payed is so shit that i cant
>   justify their defence

We don't have your contract, and we're not employment lawyers. What you need is an employment lawyer. But if you're in the US, chances are what they're doing is legal and your only recourse is to demand they change it and quit if they don't.

Comment: Very high-quality answer. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is not always available, depending on your situation (job market, etc.), but if it is available, I find it works absolutely flawlessly.

Go to as many interviews as you can, even if the job offer does not sound particularly interesting at first. This will give you the following:

1. A clear understanding of your market value (it's called job market for a reason)
2. A so-called [BATNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best_alternative_to_a_negotiated_agreement) for salary/workload negotiations (educate yourself about it, this is extremely important!)
3. Some alternatives, so you feel secure in your decisions
4. An insight into other companies and teams, etc., so you can better evaluate your current position
5. Improve your interview skills, to ensure you can grab you dream job in the future and handle being the interviewer in the future

You need to continue doing this until you get at least one good offer, preferably several (depends on job market). After that, fully armed with knowledge, you can start salary discussions with your manager. Or maybe you'll like some offer so much, that it won't even be a discussion.

However, it might happen that you don't get any offers - it means you first need to improve yourself. In that case checking what kind of interview questions you were getting (especially those you couldn't answer well) is a good first step into identifying what the companies want and improving in those things.